# What is the best way to convert unsigned integers to their octal representations and vice versa in C++?

Tags: c++, decimal, octal

Currently I'm using `while` loops:

```
std::string to_octal(unsigned int num)
{
    int place = 1, remainder, octal = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        remainder = num % 8;
        decimal /= 8;
        octal += remainder * place;
        place *= 10;
    }
    return std::to_string(octal);
}

unsigned int to_num(std::string octal)
{
    unsigned int octal_n = std::stoi(octal);
    int place = 1, remainder, num = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        remainder = octal_n % 10;
        octal_n /= 10;
        num += remainder * place;
        place *= 8;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Which seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/oct/

Comment: Better way is to keep it in native format (binary) and convert to string as necessary

Comment: integer values are always stored as binary. There is no way of changing this. You can, of course, display these binary values in whatever way you choose.

Comment: A number is a number is a number - doesn't matter how it is stored, it is still the same number. *But* you can *display* it in different bases easily if you like. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex

Comment: But that function does not do what you want - you seem to completely misunderstand how integers are stored and displayed. If you need to store an integer in a none-binary forms (which you almost certainly don't) then you need to store it as a string, and no function that returns an integer will allow you to do that.

Comment: As stated above, I am storing the octal representations as strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as decimal `unsigned int`, hexadecimal `unsigned int` or octal `unsigned int`. There is only one `unsigned int`. There is a difference only when you want to print an object of that type to the terminal or a file. From that point of view, the function

```
unsigned int decimal_to_octal(unsigned int decimal);
```

does not make sense at all. It makes sense to use:

```
struct decimal_tag {};
struct hexadecimal_tag {};
struct octal_tag {};

// Return a string that represents the number in decimal form
std::string to_string(unsigned int number, decimal_tag);

// Return a string that represents the number in hexadecimal form
std::string to_string(unsigned int number, hexadecimal_tag);

// Return a string that represents the number in octal form
std::string to_string(unsigned int number, octal_tag);
```

and their counterparts.

```
// Extract an unsigned number from the string that has decimal representation
unsigned int to_number(std::string const& s, decimal_tag);

// Extract an unsigned number from the string that has hexadecimal representation
unsigned int to_number(std::string const& s, hexadecimal_tag);

// Extract an unsigned number from the string that has octal representation
unsigned int to_number(std::string const& s, octal_tag);
```

---

Here's demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

struct decimal_tag {};
struct hexadecimal_tag {};
struct octal_tag {};

// Return a string that represents the number in decimal form
std::string to_string(unsigned int number, decimal_tag)
{
   std::ostringstream str;
   str << std::dec << number;
   return str.str();
}

// Return a string that represents the number in hexadecimal form
std::string to_string(unsigned int number, hexadecimal_tag)
{
   std::ostringstream str;
   str << std::hex << number;
   return str.str();
}

// Return a string that represents the number in octal form
std::string to_string(unsigned int number, octal_tag)
{
   std::ostringstream str;
   str << std::oct << number;
   return str.str();
}

// Extract an unsigned number from the string that has decimal representation
unsigned int to_number(std::string const& s, decimal_tag)
{
   std::istringstream str(s);
   unsigned int number;
   str >> std::dec >> number;
   return number;
}

// Extract an unsigned number from the string that has hexadecimal representation
unsigned int to_number(std::string const& s, hexadecimal_tag)
{
   std::istringstream str(s);
   unsigned int number;
   str >> std::hex >> number;
   return number;
}

// Extract an unsigned number from the string that has octal representation
unsigned int to_number(std::string const& s, octal_tag)
{
   std::istringstream str(s);
   unsigned int number;
   str >> std::oct >> number;
   return number;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned int n = 200;
   std::cout << "200 in decimal: " << to_string(n, decimal_tag()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "200 in hexadecimal: " << to_string(n, hexadecimal_tag()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "200 in octal: " << to_string(n, octal_tag()) << std::endl;

   std::cout << "Number from decimal form (200): " << to_number("200", decimal_tag()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Number from hexadcimal form (c8): " << to_number("c8", hexadecimal_tag()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Number from octal form (310): " << to_number("310", octal_tag()) << std::endl;
}
```

and its output:

```
200 in decimal: 200
200 in hexadecimal: c8
200 in octal: 310
Number from decimal form (200): 200
Number from hexadcimal form (c8): 200
Number from octal form (310): 200
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction; this is what I'm really trying to do (see edited post above). Question still remains: what is the best way to convert to and from an octal string representation of an integer in C++?

Comment: @PatrickM, I've updated my answer to offer one solution. it's hard to say what's "best". It depends on what you are looking for. If you are looking for easy to understand and maintain code, my implementation should be good. If you are looking for something that can be used millions of times without it being a bottleneck, you will probably need to use other methods.

Comment: What is the point of passing in these tags into an overloaded function, instead of giving the functions different names?

Comment: @SwissFrank, function overloading idiomatic here since the functions are essentially doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Printing numbers in different bases:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main () {
  int n = 123;
  std::cout << std::dec << n << '\n';
  std::cout << std::hex << n << '\n';
  std::cout << std::oct << n << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [An X-Y answer,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but likely the best route for this question.

Comment: question is to create a string, not to print

Answer (score 0):

This function is 5x faster than @R Sahu's solution in debug compile, and 11x faster in -O2 optimized compile.  It also works for any size unsigned int.

Permission granted for all manner of use.

```
#include <limits>

// Efficient conversion from any unsigned int type to an octal C
// string.  Argument must be unsigned, but may be ANY unsigned from
// char to long long.  Return value points to a NUL-terminated string
// in the buffer.  Single-threaded applications are supported with an
// internal buffer and can ignore this detail.  Multi-threaded
// programs must pass in their own buffer of at least the given size,
// which will be big enough to handle any octal.
  
template<typename T> const char* to_oct( T t, char* pcBuf = nullptr ) {

    static_assert( ! std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed,
                   "only works for unsigned types" );
    
    // Each byte can add no more than 3 digits to the string.  +1 for NUL.
    static char cBuf[ sizeof( T ) * 3 + 1 ];

    // Allow single-threaded callers to skip buffer argument.
    if ( ! pcBuf )
        pcBuf = cBuf;

    // Move to the end of the buffer and write a terminator.
    pcBuf += sizeof( T ) / sizeof( char ) * 3;
    *pcBuf = '\0';

    if ( t )
        // Move right to left, outputting LSD, until we have no more
        // to output.  The size of our argument dictates the maximum
        // number of loops, and our buffer is big enough to hold even
        // the maximum result.
        while ( t ) {
            *(--pcBuf) = '0' + t % 8;
            t >>= 3;
        }
    else
        // Above loop would produce no output for 0, so handle as special case.
        *(--pcBuf) = '0';

  return pcBuf;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

And of course the old C method is still working in C++: use `%o` [Format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

```
printf("%o", n);
```

use `sprintf` if you want it in a string (ok, that means you have to care of memory allocation to store the result, which is a drawback compared to `std::oct`).